# Android image Layout

Tags: android-layout

We have Layout Container with size Width = 200px and Height = 800px,  We have images of unequal Height and width,But all images size is such that all images fit in Layout Container. How to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: give more details + some code.. This is not understandable..!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use dp instead of px in android and suppose you have taken the imageview of 200dp * 200dp in **xml file** you can set the `scaleType` property to `fitXY` or any scale type suitable to you and i suggest you to also use `adjustViewBounds=true` so that any image will set to it properly you can know more about scaleType [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

I also suggest you to read [this blog](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ImageView) to understand concept behind it.

And also see these answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6670069/5476209

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124018/5476209